# Alerting the user while creating field

Tags: sharepoint, alerts

I need an help in a formula for sharepoint.

I have created issue tracking ticket, all necessary fields are filled.

Now I have a field called "Request Close day". This field should be filled with date and time while closing the ticket. Now there is another field called "Ticket Status" which is choice type having values In progress, Waiting on customer and Closed.

Now the issue is when I set the "ticket status" as closed the field "Request Close day" should be filled.If a user forgets to fill in it should alert the user to fill the "Request Close day" or it should automatically fill the date and time.

Is it possible to alert the user using the IF or Vlookup condition.

Thank you all in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in functionality for this. 
But you could achieve this by adding the logic using Javascript inside a content editor webpart. Should be quite simple to attach the necessary events using 
e.g. jQuery. something like:

$("id_of_ticketstatus").change(function(){
  $("id_of_date").val(Date.getDate());
});